# SQL query to sum up with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing SQL query to sum up values according to group assigned. I have database like:
Table A

```
+----+--------+
| id | group  |
+----+--------+
|  A1| A      |
|  A2| A      |
|  B1| B      |
+----+--------+
```

Table B:

```
+----+--------+
| id | Amount |
+----+--------+
|  A1| 10     |
|  A1| 20     |
|  B1| 5      |
|  A2| 10     |
+----+--------+
```

I wish to obtain results like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | Amount |
+----+--------+
|  A1| 40     |
|  B1| 5      |
+----+--------+
```

FYI I'm using MySQL as my DBMS
 The expected results will show the min id and add up the amount from the same group

Comment: Please double check your sample input and expected output

Comment: @1000111 It's fine, he's grouping by `TableA.group`

Comment: @1000111 Sorry, is there any problem?

Comment: got it now. thanks @sagi . At first glance I thought it was a typo.

Comment: Why `A1` is chosen over `A2`??  `min` val can be selected???

Comment: @Praveen Good question! Because I also wish to select the min

Answer (score 2):

```
select min(a.id) as id, 
       sum(b.amount) as total
from tableB b
join tableA a on a.id = b.id
group by a.`group`
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple join and group by :

```
SELECT MIN(a.id),sum(b.amount)
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
 ON(a.id = b.id)
GROUP BY a.group
```

If you specificly wanted `A1,B1` as ID, then please explain this logic.

Comment: Your query does not return the expected result

Comment: Because the expected result is not explained, the fact that `A1` is there doesn't mean he wants the minimum one. That's why I added the note.

Comment: If you don't understand the requirement - why post an answer?

Comment: So you're sure you did? Who said he cares about which one will be selected? Its even more logical to return result as my query. And as for why I posted an answer? To help him, if it's not what he wants he can comment.

Comment: @sagi sorry, I didn't stated in my question and I wish the results will get the min

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using SUM and GROUP BY?

```
SELECT SUM (Amount) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I want the table to show one player from each group only

Comment: sorry, did not get what you mean. I believe query above will show your expected result. Can you elaborate more on your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      (select top 1 A2.id from TableA as A2 where A2.[group] = A.[group]) as id,      
      sum(B.Amount) as Amount
FROM TableA as A
  left join TableB as B on B.id = A.id  
group by A.[group]
```

This code runs on MS SQL 2012. You can independently verify it works on MYSQL or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, SUM(B.amount) as amount 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.group
```

More about `join`:

[MySQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)